# Change of variable and change of region

Tags: calculus

Im going through the proof that shows $ \zeta(2) = \frac {\pi^2}{6}$ . Further down we get $ \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1-x^2 y^2}dydx $ so, we see that we're integrating over a unit square. Then, we use a variable substitution making $ x= \frac{sin(u)}{cos(v)} $ and $y=\frac{sin(v)}{cos(u)}$. After we make this substitution, our region of integration change from a unit square to a triangle with vertices $ (0,0),(\frac{\pi}{2},0), (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ Though, I don't understand  why or how this change happens.How should I go about viewing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraints:
$$ 0 \leq x =\frac{\sin u}{\cos v}\leq 1,\qquad 0\leq y=\frac{\sin v}{\cos u}\leq 1$$
translates into:
$$ 0\leq \sin u\leq \cos v=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-v\right),\qquad 0\leq \sin v\leq \cos u=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-u\right), $$
so, since $u$ and $v$ range in $\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ and the sine function is injective over such an interval, we must have:
$$ 0\leq u \leq \frac{\pi}{2}-v,\qquad 0\leq v\leq \frac{\pi}{2}-u $$
that is the same as stating $0\leq u+v\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, giving your triangular region.